# How does Ruby's to_s(2) translate into python?

Tags: python, ruby, python-cryptography

So I've been trying to rewrite a Ruby snippet of code into Python, and I haven't been able to make it work. I reread everything to make sure I did it right, but it still doesn't work. I guess the problem lies in this "translation":

```
def multiply(k, point = $G)
  current = point

  binary = k.to_s(2)

  binary.split("").drop(1).each do |char|

    current = double(current)


    current = add(current, point) if char == "1"
   end

   current
end
```

This is my translated python version:

```
def multiply(k, point = G):
    current = point
    binary = bin(k)

    for i in binary[3:]:
        current = double(current)
    
        if i == "1":
            current = add(current, point)

    return current
```

I believe I didn't quite understand Ruby's concepts of *to_s(2)* and/or *.drop(1)*.
Could someone tell me what is the best way of *translating* this Ruby code into Python?

**EDIT**
So, I'll elaborate just as @Michael Butscher suggested:

I have [this](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1DRFctHQ3TVZalyF_1ICTiBZkMM7IVOYl/view?usp=sharing) Ruby code, which I tried to translate into [this](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1-6bv2qHGVR0FjWwGNdNaWjswJvAY8p5H/view?usp=sharing) Python code. And while the output should be

`044aeaf55040fa16de37303d13ca1dde85f4ca9baa36e2963a27a1c0c1165fe2b11511a626b232de4ed05b204bd9eccaf1b79f5752e14dd1e847aa2f4db6a5`

it throws an error. Why?

Comment: You have the right equivalents: Ruby's `k.to_s(2)` is equivalent to Python's `bin(k)[2:]` and the `binary.split("").drop(1).each` syntax is equivalent to `for i in binary[1:]` (which becomes `binary[3:]` when you combine with `bin(k)`).

Comment: Explain how it doesn't work. What happens, what should happen?

Comment: In the future, please follow [help/how-to-ask] and create [example]. Make sure the question is self-contained, not everyone will want to follow external links. If there is an error, include the error message; if the code does not have an error, explain how what you want differs from the results you are getting.

Comment: Sorry, that should have been [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is not in the function you have shown, but in your `inverse` function. `/` between integers in Ruby translates as `//` in Python 3:

Ruby:

```
3 / 2
# => 1
3.0 / 2
# => 1.5
```

Python 3:

```
3 / 2
# => 1.5
3 // 2
# => 1
```

Comment: THANK YOU SO MUCH, this was so damn simple yet so impossible for me to spot. Thanks for your time and patience.

Comment: No worries. The easy way to find these kinds of things is to sprinkle enough `puts` or `print` statements around your code to see where things start to go weird.